# Can't seem to pull the text from my list item

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code and I'd really liek to be able to get the text otu of the item in the listview.  I've done an example where i can get it to toast in a different type of listview, but not this one that i made.  any helpers?
thx in advance :)

```
    private void listChoices(){
    mySQLiteAdapterChoices = new SQLiteAdapterChoices(this);
    mySQLiteAdapterChoices.openToRead();
    Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapterChoices.queueAll();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String choic=SQLiteAdapterChoices.KEY_CHOICE_SUB;

    String[] from = new String[]{choic};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textUserChoice};

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.userrow, cursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    mySQLiteAdapterChoices.close();



    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {



            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                final String text = ("txtUserChoice");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        text,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        First.class));
                break;
```

...

XML from createcontrol.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list"   

android:layout_width="305px"
android:layout_height="270px"
android:layout_x="8px"
android:layout_y="10px"
>
</ListView>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txtEdt"
android:layout_width="185px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""
android:textSize="18sp"
android:autoText="true"
android:capitalize="words"
android:layout_x="8px"
android:layout_y="293px"
>
</EditText>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnNewItem"
android:layout_width="107px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Submit"
android:layout_x="199px"
android:layout_y="295px"
>
</Button>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

xml from userrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUserChoice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fixed Code Below.. I moved some of the variables up a couple scopes and changed the code to this

```
            case 0:
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(choic); 
                final String text = cursor.getString(index);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        text,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        First.class));
                break;
            case 1:....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you forgot to fetch the data from cursor. You wrote 
`final String text = ("txtUserChoice");`
and you should write like
`int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(choic);`
`final String text = cursor.getString(index);`
and make cursor and choic variable as instance member.

Comment: yay! that fixed it!! thanks you very much! posting fixed code above!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to extract the string content from the selected item from the `ListView`:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String selection = listview.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you have selected "+selection, 5000).show();

            }
        });
```